# How to run the onlick command after I choose the item in drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick

Every time i click on the dropdown menu , the onlick trigger the function reload straight away. How can i make the function reload run after i select the item in the drop down menu list? Please help me ..

```
<form><select name="student" onclick='reload'>
<option value="A">Student A</option>
<option value="B">Student B</option>
<option value="C">Student C</option>
<option value="D">Student D</option>
<option value="E">Student E</option>
```

Comment: Try `onchange` method.it call only if changes there in select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `onClick` with `onChange`

```
<form>
<select name="student" id="student" onChange='reload'>
    <option value="A">Student A</option>
    <option value="B">Student B</option>
    <option value="C">Student C</option>
    <option value="D">Student D</option>
    <option value="E">Student E</option>
</select>
```

**ideal way to do it**

```
<script>
<!-- include the jQuery first -->
$('#student').on('change', function(e){

// reload or whatever you want to do
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="student" onChange="javascript:alert('something');">
<option value="A">Student A</option>
<option value="B">Student B</option>
<option value="C">Student C</option>
<option value="D">Student D</option>
<option value="E">Student E</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing onclick to onchange

Comment: this is not a answer use comment to OP